# Using ternary operator just for the side effect - Good or Bad?

Tags: ios, swift, ternary-operator, imperative-programming

Suppose we are using `AVKit` and we have added a `target` to our *play/pause* button to handle the playing/pausing of a track. Is it generally bad practice to use a ternary operator just for its side effect, such as below?

```
// (AVPlayer definition omitted)

@objc fileprivate func handlePlayPause() {

    (player.timeControlStatus == .playing) ? player.pause() : player.play()

}
```

The main reason I am asking this is because of the fact that side effects modify the state of a program and I believe I might have heard that you should handle side effects carefully sometime during one of my first-year courses.

Comment: I think this questions is largely opinion based.

Comment: That's ok, too. I would like to hear everyone's opinion about it

Comment: The Swift ternary conditional operator is just shorthand code for an if-else statement. When compiled into binary, the machine will handle it no differently than had you written out if-else. Swift's only warning is that it can sometimes make code less readable, a human problem, not a machine one.

Comment: Personally, I don’t see a problem with this. It isn’t really a “side effect”. It is obvious that the code will change state. A side effect would be calling a function such as “getPlayingState()” and having that function *change* the playing state; this is not implied by the name

Comment: @bsod that's very interesting!! Could you expand a little more on this? What about the fact that we are using it to run a function instead of changing the value of a variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I use them when I want to set a value to a variable, depending on a condition.

For example, let’s say that if `x == 42`, I want the variable `y` to be `true`. If `x` is not equal to 42 , then the value of the variable `y` is `false`.

So, how do I write that? Just like this…

```
let y = (x == 42) ? true : false
```

For `if-else`, I would argue and be against it.

Why? Take a look at this code:

```
var y = false

if (x == 42) {
    y = true
}
```

So we can have something like this, assuming you want it to be in one line:

```
var y = false if (x == 42) { y = true }
```

Which is ugly and unnecessary, because we can write it like this:

```
let y = (x == 42) ? true : false
```

So much cleaner! We reduced seven (4) lines of code to just one (1) line.

Ternary operators are awesome, but they’re not always needed. Suppose you just want to execute a function, or do multiple operations. don’t use ternaries.

1. Use ternary operators to set a value to a variable, or to reduce code if necessary.
2. Use if-else statements for everything else.

Comment: already you used the var y = false, then what is the use of `else {
        y = false
    }` here, if condition not matched by default it takes y = false

Comment: Your last section is shown as a quote, but where is it a quote from?  This question is opinion-based, so I don't think that you can provide a definitive answer.

Comment: @Paulw11, I have removed quote.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik, Yes, you are right. Thanks for notice.

Comment: @vacawama, Nothing is wrong. But above example differentiate between `Ternary` and `if-else` statements.

Comment: let y = (x == 42)

Comment: x == 42 already returns true or false, the ternary is entirely unnecessary in your example.

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of logic, based off an `enum`, I would choose `switch`, or an `if/else` and not ternary, since in future, I might need to put more code in there.

For example

```
if player.timeControlStatus == .playing) {
   player.pause() 
   // set a button 
} else {
   player.play()
   // un set a button 
}
```

Now you can do this, in ternary as well, but I'd fear it would render the code less readable.

Comment: but in ternary also we can use multiple lines

Comment: yup, that's what I mentioned, that we can in fact put in multiple lines, but I just feel that the code will become less readable. :)

Comment: @RX9 Happy to help. :)